# Import NPM package only for server side rendering(SSR) in Next.js App

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use one private NPM module only when the page is loading for the first time and rendering is happening on the server. I am using the following piece of code but I am still able to see my package in chunks in client.html using the build analyzer.

```
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    const content = await import('@abc/my-npm-package');
    return conent(payload);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: why not just import the module inside `getServerSideProps`? Imports used in getServerSideProps will not be bundled for the client-side.

Comment: Thanks, Nico, will try your suggestion

Answer (score 4):

Excellent question, I've poked around the Next.js's code and found out that in order to code that will be exists only on the server you need to use some variable which is passed to `webpack.DefinePlugin` (which at build time will replace the usage with the value, this what allows the tree-shake to work).

From this [line](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/a4c97c5c4adb66d733f617ce200535a968e12ba5/packages/next/build/webpack-config.ts#L947), there is a special variable `process.browser` which will be `true` only in the **browser**.

Change your code to

```js
if (!process.browser) {
  const content = await import('@abc/my-npm-package');
  return conent(payload);
} else {
  return null;
}
```

#### Update 16.03.2022

Next.js will deprecate `process.browser` soon, the new recommended way to distinguish between client & server is by checking `type of window === 'undefined' // means that it's server side`.

```js
 if (typeof window === 'undefined') { // server side
    const content = await import('@abc/my-npm-package');
    return content(payload);
  } else { // client side
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am still seeing my package in the browser chunks while analyzing.

Comment: process.window was undefined. So, I used process.browser as per code. process.browser was giving false for SSR but webpack still considering them for browser.

Comment: Ok, if this is giving a false value, that means that in PROD build the code won't exists in the bundle (as of the fact that Tree-shaking is part of minification process)

Comment: But when I run the analyzer, I am able to see the package in the client.html

Comment: Do you run in production mode? Analyzer in Next.js shows 2 results client & server, make sure that you watching at the client result

Comment: Yes, I am running in production mode and watching at client result i.e client.html

Comment: weird... can you prepare a demo repo that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot felixmosh. Sure will do that and reach you if necessary.